# Is it necessary to add Java.naming.provider.url in the start.sh script when enabling JMS caching?

Tags: web8.5, microservices, jms

When installing the SDL Tridion Cache Channel via JMS we set up the necessary topic and topic connection factory in WebSphere and updated the cd_storage_conf.xml of the deployer and content services to (a) enable the ObjectCache (b) add the RemoteSynchronization element.

However, we received the following error in an orbtrc file generated directly in the root of the micro service installation folder:

```
11:28:49.459 com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate _createRequest:1234 P=123456:O=0:CT ORBRas[default]  org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: Can't assign requested address (connect failed):host=[server.ip.address],port=0  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E02  completed: No
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:427)
```

We resolved this by adding the following to the JVM_OPTIONS in the start.sh script of the deployer and content services:

`-DJava.naming.provider.url=corbaloc::[server.url]:[server.port]`

Is this a common step or is this a suggestion that we have set something else up incorrectly?

I’d have assumed that the service would know about the Java.naming.provider.url values because they were defined in the RemoteSynchronization element of the cd_storage_conf.xml files, but apparently that’s not the case.

**DEPLOYER** cd_storage_conf.xml

```
<RemoteSynchronization FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="20000" Queuesize="256" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000">
    <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Strategy="AsyncJMS11MDB" Topic="jms/trdnCcsTPK" TopicConnectionFactory="jms/trdnCcsTCF">
        <JndiContext>
            <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"/>
            <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="corbaloc::[server.url]:[server.port]"/>
        </JndiContext>
    </Connector>
</RemoteSynchronization>
```

**CONTENT** cd_storage_conf.xml

```
<RemoteSynchronization FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="20000" Queuesize="256" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000">
    <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Strategy="SyncJMS11" Topic="jms/trdnCcsTPK" TopicConnectionFactory="jms/trdnCcsTCF">
        <JndiContext>
            <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"/>
            <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="corbaloc:iiop:[serverl.url]:[server.port]"/>
        </JndiContext>
    </Connector>
</RemoteSynchronization>
```

Comment: What does your RemoteSynchronization config look like? Do you have a JndiContext block?

Comment: Yep we do, I've updated the question to show the values in the deployer and content  service cd_storage_conf.xml